# In Postgres, can an isolation level be set as mandatory?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, isolation-level

At https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Serializable#PostgreSQL_Implementation, it says

> Any transaction which is run at a transaction isolation level other than SERIALIZABLE will not be affected by SSI. If you want to enforce business rules through SSI, all transactions should be run at the SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation level, and that should probably be set as the default.

Instead of merely setting SERIALIZABLE as the default, can we make it the only allowed isolation level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, all you can do is set the `default_transaction_isolation` parameter to `serializable` and hope that nobody explicitly selects a different isolation level.